# Is there any way for me to get an infinity gun at level 36 in borderlands 2?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2

I'm a level 36 Zer0 and I'm wondering if there's an easier way to farm for an infinity gun

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity) wiki page, the best enemies for farming infinity are Doc Mercy, the guy from Zed's quest, and the Gold Golem in the mines from the Tiny Tina DLC.

Comment: Are there any alternative bosses that don't involve owning any DLC?

Comment: Well, Doc Mercy isn't in any DLC, he is in Three Horns - Valley

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get it, is the end boss in the Tiny Tina DLC. He often drop very good weapons. I got 2 infinities just from him.

Off-Topic: I would suggest the unkept harold as it has much more damage and can be easily farmed in the Torgue DLC at the bar. But anyway, it depends on your skill. You want it for the first shot skill, right?

Comment: Are there any alternative bosses that don't involve owning any DLC?

Comment: Yes, you can go to doc mercy, he has a higher drop chance. Doc Mercy is the boss you'll need to kill during the tutorial phase where you get a E-Tech weapon and should clean an area with that (a mission from Doctor Zed). You can read more about it here: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Doc_Mercy

You can farm him too. He has a higher chance to drop it. But the other stuff he is dropping is mostly crap. I normally try farming in the Marcus Mercenary Shop DLC which has also a good chance (not as high as doc mercy) but if there is no infinity, there is mostly something else which is great. :-)